# exporting value from specific div in html page in python

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

i have html page with multiple div's called "rptTopics_rptTopicTechnics_[X]_lblTechnicalValue_0"
each X has different value 
html code sample :

```
 <div class="specific_info_txt">
                                                                    <span 
 id="rptTopics_rptTopicTechnics_10_lblTechnicalValue_0" dir="ltr">Starting: 
  2.kg</span>
                                                                </div>
```

i want the code to run and find me the specific div that contain the string "kg"

i did that :

```
def get_weight(desc):
 a = 1
 for span in desc:
  weight = sec.find_element_by_id('rptTopics_rptTopicTechnics_' + str(a) + '_lblTechnicalValue_0').text
  if ('kg' in weight or 'ק"ג' in weight or 'KG' in weight or 'Kg' in weight):
    Fweight  = weight
    break
  else:
    a += 1
 return Fweight
```

that didn't work... what is the right way to read all div's and get the right one ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Please post the error message. It may also be useful to post the url.

Comment: hi, it didn't work means - i dint get the value from the html. - i will add the html scrapped code

Comment: @Jack Fleeting - can you see now the issue ?

Comment: I think you should put the error code. In your code i see at least one thing very strange, what is sec? (don't you mean span?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the driver function **find_elements_by_xpath** plus an XPath that will find those elements for you. For example:

```py
def get_weight():
    # Find all the spans that are under the div with class 'specific_info_txt'
    # and the children span contains the id 'rptTopics_rptTopicTechnics_'

    spans = sec.find_elements_by_xpath("*//div[@class,'specific_info_txt']/span[contains(@id,'rptTopics_rptTopicTechnics_')"]

    # In case that for some reason the weight is not found in the page
    Fweight = None

    # Loop over the found spans
    for span in spans:
        weight = span.text

        if ('kg' in weight or 'ק"ג' in weight or 'KG' in weight or 'Kg' in weight):
            Fweight  = weight
            break

    return Fweight
```